# List of lists value in dictionary?

Tags: python

Input file 'test.txt':

```
a 2012 fff

b 2011 ttt

a 2011 fff

b 2012 sss

a 2011 vvv
```

I have determined the following code to populate dictionary and sort values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
with open('test.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        field0, field1, field2 = line.split()
        res[field0] += [field1, field2]

for i in res.keys():
    print i, sorted(res[i], key=lambda x: x[0])
```

However, this yields "a [2011, 2011, 2012, fff, fff, vvv]" and I want output to be in the exact same format as the input (but sorted):

```
a 2011 fff

a 2011 vvv

a 2012 fff
```

I can't just use sort on the original input since I will be referencing multiple times and need to store in memory. Should value for each line be stored in a list (ie. dictionary value is list of lists)?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you need a `dict` built like that for your own reason.

You need to change this line:

```
res[field0] += [field1, field2]
```

with:

```
res[field0].append((field1, field2))
```

And then sort like this:

```
for key in sorted(res):
    for pair in sorted(res[key]):
        print '{0} {pair[0]} {pair[1]}'.format(key, pair=pair)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for!  I just changed the sorting to be a bit more succinct:                                                `for key in res.keys():                                                      `    print key, sorted(res[key])

Comment: @Christopher: You're welcome, I assumed you wanted to sort on the keys too, but you got the point. Can I then expect you'll [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/177799) this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `[field1, field2]` to `(field1, field2)` to group the fields while sorting. You can then output like this:

```
for i in res.keys():
    for pair in sorted(res[i]):
        print i, ' '.join(pair)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a list where each entry is the result of `line.split()`, and then sort that list to get the correct order:

```
res = []
with open('test.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        res.append(line.split())

res.sort()
for i in res:
    print ' '.join(i)
```

After reading the file `res` would look like this:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(res)
[['a', '2012', 'fff'],
 ['b', '2011', 'ttt'],
 ['a', '2011', 'fff'],
 ['b', '2012', 'sss'],
 ['a', '2011', 'vvv']]
```

And then after `res.sort()` you would have the following, which is the order you want:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(sorted(res))
[['a', '2011', 'fff'],
 ['a', '2011', 'vvv'],
 ['a', '2012', 'fff'],
 ['b', '2011', 'ttt'],
 ['b', '2012', 'sss']]
```

This works because sequence types are compared lexicographically; the first items are compared; if they are the same then the second items are compared, and so on. <sup>[[source]](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This should get them all sorted for you.  It does a normal sorted() by each of the tuple positions in order and is easily customized.

```
res = []

with open('test.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.strip():
            f = line.split()
            res.append( (f[0], int(f[1]), f[2]) )

fullysorted = sorted(res, key=lambda tup: (tup[0], tup[1], tup[2]))

for i in fullysorted:
    print '%s %i %s' % (i)
```

Returns:

```
a 2011 fff
a 2011 vvv
a 2012 fff
b 2011 ttt
b 2012 sss
```

(I also assume you want the year as an int, rather than a string)

Answer (score 0):

if you just need sorted lines do this:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    res = sorted(f)
```

if you need the lines split, do this:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    res = sorted(line.split() for line in f)
```

If your second column isn't always four digits you'll need to tell `sorted` to treat it as an integer:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    res = sorted((line.split()) for line in f), key=lambda x:(x[0], int(x[1]), x[2]))
```